# Most efficient way to calculate the first day of the current Financial Year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's the most efficient way to calculate the first day of the current (Australian) Financial Year?

The Australian FY begins on 01-July.

E.g.

`SELECT dbo.FinancialYearStart('30-Jun-2011')` returns 01-Jul-2010.

`SELECT dbo.FinancialYearStart('01-Jul-2011')` returns 01-Jul-2011.

`SELECT dbo.FinancialYearStart('02-Jul-2011')` returns 01-Jul-2011.

Comment: Efficiency for one date (like now) is not important really. If you want to find however, the first days of the (Australian) Financial Years for dates stored in a table, that's quite different.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One DATEADD, one DATEDIFF, and a division:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(month,'19010701','20110630')/12,'19010701')
```

Basically, you count the number of months since some arbitrary financial year's start date (I've picked 1901), divide that number by 12 (ignoring the remainder), and add that many years back to the same arbitrary year's start date.

Comment: Clever workaround for the [DATEPART boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) issues I ran into when trying something similar: `SELECT DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'19010701','20110630'),'19010701')`

Comment: Every time someone asks a datetime question, I try to make it fit into the DATEADD/DATEDIFF pattern - and as you say, I have to do it this way to cope with what DATEDIFF actually calculates.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the most efficient, but it's fast at least...

```
create function dbo.FinancialYearStart
(
   @CurrentDate datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin
   declare @CurrentYear int
          ,@FYDateThisYear datetime
          ,@FYDatePrevYear datetime

   set @CurrentYear = datepart(year, @CurrentDate)
   set @FYDateThisYear = '01-Jul-' + cast(@CurrentYear as varchar(4))
   set @FYDatePrevYear = '01-Jul-' + cast(@CurrentYear-1 as varchar(4))

   if @CurrentDate < @FYDateThisYear
   begin
      return @FYDatePrevYear
   end

   return @FYDateThisYear
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the year and month from the date. Then do `year = year + FLOOR((month-7) / 6)`

Then your date is 1-jul-year

(You don't actually need to store them as variables.)

Something like: `CONCATENATE('01-jul-', YEAR(date) + FLOOR((MONTH(date)-7) / 6)`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat sophisticated method (maybe a tiny little bit too much):

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(month,
          (MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1) / 6 * 12 - 6,
          CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar) AS datetime)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Clunky but it works

```
select
    cast('01-Apr-' +
         cast(
            case
               when datepart(mm,getdate()) in (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) 
           then DATEPART(yy,getdate()) 
           else DATEPART(yy,getdate())-1 
            end as varchar
         ) as datetime
    ) as fy_start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  cast(cast(YEAR(getdate())-
        (case 
            when MONTH(GETDATE()) between 1 and 6 then 1
            else 0
        end) as varchar)+'0701' as date)
```